# DD-WRT As an access point for VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, dd-wrt, wireless-access-point

I want to set up a home VPN, and I had planned to use DD-WRT to do it. The problem is that our current router isn't supported by DD-WRT. Our previous router is supported by DD-WRT, and I have already installed the firmware on that router. The problem is that for a few reasons, we need to use the router that doesn't support DD-WRT as our primary router. What I'm wondering is: is it possible to set up a DD-WRT router as an access point on an existing network not run by a DD-WRT router, and then still use that router to set up a home VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just make sure to do these things:

1. Disable WAN support in the DD-WRT router. Either configure it to bridge the WAN port to its LAN (converting it into another LAN port) or don't use the WAN/Internet port.
2. Connect a LAN port on one router to a LAN port on the other.
3. Disable the DHCP server in the DD-WRT router.
4. Configure the DD-WRT router's LAN IP to a valid IP inside the subnet, ideally one outside the other router's DHCP range. Set its default gateway to the IP address of the other router.

Comment: For the last step: "Set its default gateway to the IP address of the other router", do you mean the local ip address, or the outside ip address?

Comment: @CodeJunkie: The local IP address. Your default gateway has to be on the same network as you, otherwise you'd need a gateway to reach it, and then that would be your default gateway.